# What is the probability that two subsets have the same sum?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let's say that we have a set of seven positive integers $A = \{a_1,a_2, \dots, a_7\}$ such that $$1\leq a_i \leq 24, \forall i=1,\dots,7.$$ I am trying to calculate the probability that, choosing two random subsets of $A$ (namely $A_1$ and $A_2$), we have that the sum of the elements of $A_1$ is equal to the sum of the elements of $A_2$.

One can also extend this question with a set $A$ with $n$ totally random integers, but this might be another history.

Comment: How do you choose the $a_1,a_2, \dots, a_7$?  $24^7$ equally probable ways or $\frac{24!}{17!}$ equally probable ways or something else?  How do you choose $A_1$ and $A_2$?  Independently each in $2^7$ equally probable ways or something else?

Comment: @Henry All the integers $a_1,\dots,a_7$ are fixed from the beginning and they have a probability of $\frac{1}{24}$ of being a fixed number $j$ between $1$ and $24$. $A_1$ and $A_2$ are uniformly choosen, so $2^7$.

Comment: I would use simulation.  My unchecked estimate is about $0.022$ for this particular question

Comment: @Henry Indeed, 0.02168. See my answer for the exact fraction.

Comment: Can $A_1=A_2$ or must the two subsets be different?

Comment: @paw88789 Well, if $A_1 = A_2$ then the problem is trivial. Since we are taken the subsets randomly, it can happen (with negligible probability).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encode the choice of a subset in the generating function
$$P(q) = \frac{1}{2^7} \prod_{i=1}^7 (1+q^{a_i}).$$
This is the probability generating function of the "sum" random variable on uniformly sampled subsets of $\{a_1, \ldots, a_7\}$. The coefficient of $q^k$ is the probability that you'll get a sum of $k$. In a similar way, the difference of two independent uniformly sampled subsets has probability generating function $P(q)P(q^{-1})$. So, the answer is:
$$\text{probability of subsets having same sum} = \text{the constant coefficient of }P(q)P(q^{-1}).$$

It's easy to have a computer calculate this. It can do so efficiently by taking advantage of FFT's for the polynomial multiplications. I doubt there's a better general answer; undoubtedly the exact answer is simply delicate to compute for general $\{a_1, \ldots, a_7\}$.

**Edit:** The original post is vague, but it seems that perhaps the subset $\{a_1, \ldots, a_7\}$ is not fixed after all and is also randomly chosen. From the comments, it further seems it's not really a subset either, namely repeats are allowed, and actually the $a_i$ are just i.i.d. uniform random variables (i.e. no order is imposed). In that case, the probability generating function for first choosing the $\{a_1, \ldots, a_7\}$'s, then choosing two subsets, then taking their difference is
$$\frac{1}{24^7} \sum_{(a_1, \ldots, a_7) \in [24]^7} P(q)P(q^{-1}).$$

This simplifies dramatically:
$$\begin{align*}
  \sum_{(a_1, \ldots, a_7) \in [24]^7} \prod_{i=1}^7 (1+q^{a_i})(1+q^{-a_i})
  &= \prod_{i=1}^7 \sum_{a \in [24]} (1+q^a)(1+q^{-a}) \\
  &= \left(\sum_{a=1}^{24} (q^a + 2 + q^{-a})\right)^7 \\
  &= \left(q\frac{1-q^{24}}{1-q} + 48 + q^{-1}\frac{1-q^{-24}}{1-q^{-1}}\right)^7 \\
\end{align*}$$

In this version of the problem, the answer is
$$\text{the constant coefficient of }\frac{1}{96^7} \left(q\frac{1-q^{24}}{1-q} + 48 + q^{-1}\frac{1-q^{-24}}{1-q^{-1}}\right)^7.$$

Mathematica computes this easily:

[image: exact]